# `getdescriptorinfo` for private key

Tags: private-key, output-script-descriptors, checksum

Public key:

```
bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wpkh(027fda10f37e6c637a1cfeba2cbada86de36f28e63d4ded9e1314117739f6419a9)"
{
  "descriptor": "wpkh(027fda10f37e6c637a1cfeba2cbada86de36f28e63d4ded9e1314117739f6419a9)#99knjm9r",
  "checksum": "99knjm9r",
  "isrange": false,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": false
}
```

Private key:

```
bitcoin-cli getdescriptorinfo "wpkh(cRLX3mChef5FEFi6y46yH1YJ4Cy7K3WW4bJDBZ7LiygKp4CBsF6p)"
{
  "descriptor": "wpkh(027fda10f37e6c637a1cfeba2cbada86de36f28e63d4ded9e1314117739f6419a9)#99knjm9r",
  "checksum": "s5qjl8cq",
  "isrange": false,
  "issolvable": true,
  "hasprivatekeys": true
}
```

1. What is the correct way to use private keys in descriptors?
2. Why are two checksums returned in `getdescriptorinfo` for private key?
3. Why does the KEY inside parenthesis change when using private key with `getdescriptorinfo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptors with a private key (or xprv) in it are equivalent to their version with the public key instead, apart from also conveying the private key information.

1. For what purpose?
2. The `descriptor` field only reports the descriptor itself (i.e., without private key material). The `checksum` field reports the checksum for your input. This is also explained in the help text for the RPC.
3. It's removing private key material.

Comment: 1. I wanted to import a descriptor using private key but had no checksum. Used `getdescriptorinfo` to see checksum. 2. and 3. Yes it all makes sense now. I carefully looked at results again after reading your answer. Thanks.